# php send command to port (via tcp)

Tags: php, tcp

I am looking for a php script to trigger commands to a specific port via tcp. The script is running on the same machine that I would like to send those commands to, so the ip is 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

The command will be defined be whatever is written behind the url. For example, trigger.php?screen will send command 'screen', trigger.php?sound will send command 'sound' etc.

Is this possible? I don't have much coding knowledge.

This is it in a nutshell: when I open 127.0.0.1/trigger.php?sound I would like command sound to be sent to 127.0.0.1 port 33000 via tcp. If this is easier to implement with html or cgi, that would be fine, too.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some research about sending a telnet command via php and found a script similar to what I need. I have modified it and added user3134164's line to get the command name.

Script looks like this and works perfectly. I open phptrigger.php?command and whatever I put behind the question mark will be executed just as planned. Thanks a lot for your help, user3134164 :)

```
<?php
    $socket = fsockopen("localhost", "33000", $errno, $errstr); 
    $cmd=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 

    if($socket) 
    { 
        echo "Connected. <br /><br />"; 
    }
    else 
    { 
        echo "Connection failed!<br /><br />"; 
    }

    fputs($socket, "get /$cmd \r\n"); 
    $buffer = ""; 

    while(!feof($socket)) 
    { 
        $buffer .=fgets($socket, 4096); 
    } 

    print_r($buffer); 
    echo "<br /><br /><br />"; 

    var_dump($buffer); 

    fclose($socket); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger.php would go like this (changing an example from http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php
to fit your problem;)

```
<?php
$DEBUG=1;

if ($DEBUG) {
     print "<pre>\n";
     error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
     ini_set("display_errors", 1);
     ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
}
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
    $cmd=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; //get the command name
else
    $cmd="";

print "Command to trigger: $cmd\n";
if ($cmd!="") {
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if ($socket === false) {
        echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
    } else {
        if ($DEBUG) print "Socket created successfully\n";
        $result = socket_connect($socket, "127.0.0.1", 33000);
        if ($result === false) {
            echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
        } else {
            if ($DEBUG) print "Connected successfully\n";
            socket_write($socket, $cmd, strlen($cmd));
            //Read and output possible response from the command sent
            echo "Response: ";
            while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
                echo $out;
            }
        }
        socket_close($socket);
    }
}
if ($DEBUG) print "The end.</pre>\n";

?>
```

(Note i did not run it or do syntax check but looks like it might be what you want)

Comment: Thanks for the help. This does not seem to work though. When I open that php file in the browser nothing will be displayed and no trigger is sent, either. At least according to my logfiles nothing reached the script listening to port 33000...

Comment: There are a few unknowns in the server you use as you understand so we cannot test the whole system. But I added some debugging for the script itself so we know what happened (if it got the command ok from HTTP, if it opened the socket/port if it reached your server etc.) Let us know of the output and the problem area shall reveal itself!

Comment: It is an apache2 webserver running on Debian in a VirtualBox. Nothing shows up in the browser when I open the php file. The script I would like to trigger by opening this website logs every access on this specific port (usually `GET /command HTTP/1.1` when I access it by running ip:33000/command, which is an awful solution); when I run this php, nothing shows up in the log. For testing purposes, I have send telnet pings to that ip&port from another device in my network and those do show up in the log. I made this php 0755, is that correct?

Comment: You never mentioned you want to convert commands to HTTP and your server is a web server. So you just had to add "GET /$cmd" instead of just $cmd and HTTP headers (because you do not really want to send the command to the server but you want to translate the command to an HTTP request containing the command). There was no way to get that from your question - but just add HTTP headers and GET.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am still learning and didn't know that this was essential to mention. The script works perfectly now though :)